# how to uninstall mongodb on mac ? Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, uninstallation

### i have run the following commands to remove mongodb from the launch/startup and to uninstall it using Homebrew:

```
launchctl list | grep mongo

launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb

pkill -f mongod

brew uninstall mongodb
```